# IIS 6.0 Integrated Auth Fails After 401 and Successful Login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, iis-6, windows-authentication

We have several IIS6 .NET 4.0 web applications within an enterprise environment that leverage Windows Integrated Authentication on an Intranet Zone. All applications were working correctly and as expected until recently. After a "rebuild" of several user accounts that necessitated a username change (don't ask why, I have no idea), users with the "new" accounts are unable to access some of the Integrated Auth applications, but not all.

What we are seeing now for users with workstations not joined to the domain is:

1. User request results in 401 as expected, which opens the NTLM Dialog
2. Fiddler reports valid request and response that includes default 401 message
3. Request is logged in IIS log file as 401 User enters proper credentials (domain\username + password)
4. Successive request hangs and browser (IE, FF, Safari, and Chrome tested) status just spins
5. Fiddler reports value GET Request, but no response ever occurs
6. IIS Does not log the GET after auth and we never see the 200 response that we see on the functioning applications.

As I said, this is only affecting the newly created accounts.

This is impacting 2 of 4 integrated auth applications, all in a first level Virtual Directory from the root. The other two are still functioning as expected. We've moved into dedicated app pool and that does not resolve. We even have 1 impacted application using the same app pool as a still functioning application, and still there is no function. The Web Root does not and cannot use Integrated Auth.

Comment: And it occurs to me that this might be better suited for ServerFault...but I'm a dev, so blah.